# how to "return" the swapped value of two numbers from the function in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, return

```
class Solution{
    static List<Integer> get(int a,int b)
    {
    a=a+b;
    b=a-b;
    a=a+b;
//**What will be the return statement?**
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Since [Java is pass-by-value always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), we would need to return an object of some kind, holding the swapped values for `a` and `b`.

Comment: Your method should return a `List` according to your signature.

Comment: You don't need the three lines you've already written in that method.  You just need to return the list, with the values swapped.  You could consider using the `Arrays.asList` method, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your question/doubt is not that clear but I'm guessing that what you need is something like this:

The super easy fast solution:

```
public List<Integer> swapInput(int a, int b) {
    return Arrays.asList(b, a);
}
```

The long (not that necessary) solution:

```
public List<Integer> swapInput(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("----- Before swap -----");
    System.out.println("First: " + a);
    System.out.println("Second: " + b);

    //First parameter is assigned to a temporary var
    int temporary = a;
    //Second parameter will be now assigned as first
    a = b;
    //The temporary parameter (which contains the initial value of the first parameter) is assigned as second
    b = temporary;

    System.out.println("----- After swa -----");
    System.out.println("First: " + a);
    System.out.println("Second: " + b);

    return Arrays.asList(a, b);
}
```